# Odd fp double register number Mips assembly while running the program and second is another thing error in 2nd program it says in output -1.#ND0000

Tags: assembly, mips

first code that has fpp odd number while running the program when it asks the third value

```
.data
    # Define constants and data
    enhancement_factor: .float 5.0   # Enhancement factor for the floating-point unit
    initial_execution_time: .float 100.0  # Initial execution time in seconds

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Initialize registers and variables
    li $t0, 0          # Loop counter for 10% intervals (0 to 10)
    li $t1, 10

loop:
    # Calculate the proportion of fp-calculation time (in 10% intervals)
    li $t2, 10         # Total intervals
    div $t0, $t2       # Calculate proportion (0.0 to 1.0) as $t0 / $t2
    mflo $t3           # Store the integer result in $t3

    # Convert $t3 to floating-point and store it in $f10
    mtc1 $t3, $f10

    # Calculate the corresponding total execution time (T_after)
    lwc1 $f11, initial_execution_time  # Load initial_execution_time into $f11
    mul.s $f11, $f10, $f11  # $f11 = proportion * initial_execution_time
    add.s $f12, $f11, $f11  # $f12 = T_after = 2 * proportion * initial_execution_time

    # Calculate the speedup using Amdahl's law formula
    # S = 1 / ((F_fp * (1 + (1 / I_fp))) + (F_other / I_other))
    # Here, we assume F_fp = $f10, I_fp = enhancement_factor, F_other = (1 - $f10), I_other = 1.0
    li.s $f13, 1.0      # Initialize $f13 to 1.0 (for I_other)
    lwc1 $f15, enhancement_factor  # Load enhancement_factor into $f15
    div.s $f14, $f13, $f15  # $f14 = 1 / I_fp
    add.s $f14, $f14, $f13  # $f14 = 1 + (1 / I_fp)
    mul.s $f10, $f10, $f14  # $f10 = F_fp * (1 + (1 / I_fp))
    div.s $f10, $f13, $f10  # $f10 = 1 / ($f10) (final value of F_fp)

    # Calculate the speedup (S)
    div.s $f0, $f11, $f12  # $f0 = 1 / T_after
    div.s $f0, $f13, $f0  # $f0 = S = 1 / (F_fp * (1 + (1 / I_fp)) + (F_other / I_other))

    # Print the proportion and speedup values
    li $v0, 2           # Print float
    mov.s $f12, $f0     # Move speedup value to $f12
    syscall

    li $v0, 4           # Print string
    la $a0, newline     # Load newline string address
    syscall

    # Check if we have reached the end of the loop (11 rows)
    beq $t0, $t1, end_loop

    # Otherwise, increment the loop counter and repeat the loop
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j loop

end_loop:
    # Exit the program
    li $v0, 10          # Exit syscall
    syscall

.data
newline: .asciiz "\n"
```

in 2nd it gives output
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
-1.#ND00000
2.0000000

```
.data
prompt_T:       .asciiz "Enter the total execution time (T): "
prompt_N:       .asciiz "Enter the improvement in floating-point time (N, 0-20): "
prompt_t2:      .asciiz "Enter the time spent on floating-point operations (t2): "
result:         .asciiz "Speedup (S): "
error_msg:      .asciiz "Error: N must be in the range 0-20\n"
error_msg_zero: .asciiz "Error: N cannot be zero\n"

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Prompt the user to enter T
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt_T
    syscall

    # Read T from the user
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    mov.d $f0, $f12   # Store T in $f0

    # Prompt the user to enter N (improvement factor)
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt_N
    syscall

    # Read N from the user
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    mtc1.d $v0, $f2  # Convert N to double and store in $f2

    # Check if N is within the range 0-20
    c.le.d $f31, $f2  # Check if N <= 20
    c.lt.d $f2, $f0   # Check if N >= 0
    bc1f error_n      # Branch to error if out of range

    # Prompt the user to enter t2
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt_t2
    syscall

    # Read t2 from the user
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    mtc1.d $v0, $f4  # Convert t2 to double and store in $f4

    # Calculate Speedup (S) only if N is not zero
    c.eq.d $f2, $f31  # Check if N is zero
    bc1t error_n_zero # Branch to error if N is zero
    nop

    div.d $f0, $f0, $f4  # T / t2
    div.d $f0, $f0, $f2  # (T / t2) / N

    # Print the result (Speedup)
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall
    mov.d $f12, $f0
    li $v0, 3
    syscall

    # Exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

error_n:
    # Print an error message for N out of range
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error_msg
    syscall
    j main
    nop

error_n_zero:
    # Print an error message for N being zero
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error_msg_zero
    syscall
    j main
    nop
```

IM TRYING TO SOLVE THE FOLLOWING QUESTIONS
?

Task I (2 marks): write a MIPS program which implements the calculation steps in Exercise 1
from Amdahls-Law.pdf for a wider range of values entered from the keyboard (it allows
arbitrary input values for relevant parameters). Use floating point instructions where
appropriate. Your program should perform the tasks as listed below:
 Read in from the keyboard decimal fraction value T, where T is the total execution time of
some benchmark before the floating point enhancement (in Exercise 1 from AmdahlsLaw.pdf, T is 10 sec);
 Read in from the keyboard decimal fraction value N, where N is the amount of improvement
to floating point instruction running time only (in Exercise 1 from Amdahls-Law.pdf, N =
5). Restrict the range of ‘N’ to 0-20, and generate an error message asking for correct input
if this condition is not satisfied;
 Read in from the keyboard decimal fraction value t2, where t2 is the time in the original
program (before improvement) spent doing floating-point operations (in Exercise 1 from
Amdahls-Law.pdf, t2 = 6);
hint: T, N, and t2 are decimal fraction numbers, for example: T=12.35, N=1.25, t2=7.10
 Calculate the Speedup.
3. Task II (1 mark): write a program which implements the calculation steps to the Exercise 3
from Amdahls-Law.pdf (while you can reuse the code for Task I, please note that the formula in
Task II is different from that in Task I).
 Assume that we enhance the floating-point unit which is running 5 times faster. The program
of Task II should produce a table (a list) of overall Speedup for test programs changing with
the proportion of fp-calculation time to the total execution time. The proportion of fpcalculation time to the total execution time changes from 0% (0.0) to 100% (1.0). For Task
II implementation, use 10% intervals (not 25% intervals as in Exercise 3), i.e. the list will
contain 11 rows of value pairs of overall Speedup and the fraction of fp-calculation time.

Comment: Use even register numbers with doubled.